# 3D World to Local transformation

Tags: math, 3d, ogre3d

I am having a real headache trying to set a node's **local** position to match a given **world** position.

I was given a solution but, AFAICS, it only takes into account **orientation** and **position** but **NOT scaling** :

```
node_new_local_position = node_parent.derivedOrientation().Inverse() * ( world_position_to_match - node_parent.derivedPosition() );
```

The node in question is a child of **node_parent**; node_parent **local** and **derived** properties (orientation, position and scaling) are known, as well as its **full matrix transform**.

All the positions are **3d vectors**; the orientation is a **quaternion**; the full transform is a 4x4 matrix.

Could someone please help me to modify the solution to support scaling in the node hierarchy?

Many thanks in advance,

Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert in ogre3d but I guess you would need something like:

```
 node_new_local_position =  node_parent._getFullTransform ().inverse() * world_position_to_match;
```

where `_getFullTransform ().inverse()` is a full `4 x 4` inverse of `node_parents` transform.

**EDIT:** It looks like maybe you should just use `_setDerivedPosition` which does exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I didn't imagine it would be that simple! Thanks!

Comment: @Bill Sometimes you get lucky ;)